# Cannot create view instance while testing the backbone view using jasmine

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jasmine

I am using jasmine framework for testing the backbone.js view .I am creating instance of the view using following code:`var listview = new employee_list_view();` in `SpecRunner.html`
and in my `test.js` file i have following code:

```
 var employee_list_view = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#employee'),
model:Person,
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind("add", this.render, this);

},
```

But after running the test cases I got following error:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new employee_list_view()')
```

I have tried lot but i ended with the same error.Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Can you please tell the order in which files are loaded ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="supporting/jquery-1.8.0-min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you move jQuery on top of all scripts ? And put `var listview = new employee_list_view();` in `$(document).ready({ })` in `specRunner.html`. Give it a try.

Comment: No dude i am getting listView undefined

Comment: Ohh :( :(

Where exactly you're trying to access `listView` so that its saying its `undefined` ? And try to debug the script which initializes view to see whether `employee_list_view` reference is available there or not, you can use firebug.

And yes as `@mvbl fst` said, pass an instance of collection or comment the line for time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you did not instantiate the view.

Do `var list_view = new employee_list_view({ collection: collection });`